# An identity obtained by partial integration

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

$u(r,z,t)$ is a vector-value function.what we know as follow$\Delta=\partial_r^2+\dfrac{1}{r}\partial_r+\dfrac{1}{r^2}\partial_{\theta}^2+\partial_z^2,\nabla=e_r\partial_r+\dfrac{e_{\theta}}{r}\partial_{\theta}+e_z\partial_z$.
we will denote that $\lVert f\rVert_{L^2}^2=\int\lvert f\rvert^2rdrdz,dx=rdrdz$.
Note that $u=u(r,z,t)$.Therefore $\partial_{\theta}u=0$.
Now why the identity is true in the following ? I hope to know the caculations step by step.I have tried 2 hours.Thanks.
Using integration by parts,we have 
$-\int\dfrac{u_r}{r}(\Delta+\dfrac{2}{r}\partial_r)\dfrac{u_r}{r}dx=\lVert \nabla\dfrac{u_r}{r}\rVert_{L^2}^2+\int\lvert \dfrac{u_r(0,z,t)}{r}\rvert^2 dz$

Note:this question is a step of lemma 2.1 in the following paper.
Wei D. Regularity criterion to the axially symmetric Navier–Stokes equations[J]. Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications, 2016, 435(1): 402-413.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh,I have got the answer.

$-\int\dfrac{u_r}{r}(\Delta+\dfrac{2}{r}\partial_r)\dfrac{u_r}{r}dx=-\int\dfrac{u_r}{r}\Delta\dfrac{u_r}{r}dx-\int\dfrac{u_r}{r}\dfrac{2}{r}\partial_r\dfrac{u_r}{r}dx$=$-\int\dfrac{u_r}{r}\Delta\dfrac{u_r}{r}dx+\int\lvert \dfrac{u(0,z,t)}{r}\rvert^2dz$

Now,$-\int\dfrac{u_r}{r}\Delta\dfrac{u_r}{r}dx=-\int u_r\partial_r^2\dfrac{u_r}{r}drdz-\int u_r\partial_z^2\dfrac{u_r}{r}dzdr-\int u_r\dfrac{1}{r}\partial_r\dfrac{u_r}{r}drdz$

Then,using integration by parts,we will have
$-\int u_r\partial_r^2\dfrac{u_r}{r}drdz=\int\partial_ru_r\partial_r\dfrac{u_r}{r}drdz,-\int u_r\partial_z^2\dfrac{u_r}{r}drdz=\int\dfrac{(\partial_zu_r)^2}{r}drdz$
$-\int u_r\dfrac{1}{r}\partial_r\dfrac{u_r}{r}drdz+\int\partial_ru_r\partial_r\dfrac{u_r}{r}drdz+\int\dfrac{(\partial_zu_r)^2}{r}drdz=\lVert \nabla\dfrac{u_r}{r}\rVert_{L^2}^2$

Now the proof is completed.